# PayPay Developer account access and production

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am having another developer do the PayPal integration for an app.  I want to allow them to do this without giving them access to the real bank account information or anything about the PayPal account which would allow them to have access during production.  They requested that I make a PayPal Developer Account and provide the Client ID, Client Secret Key., and Merchant Name.
Do I create a PayPal developer account and give the developer full access to it by giving them the login?  Then when the app goes into production how does it use the live PayPal business account without the developer being involved?

Can someone explain the correct process in having a developer do the PayPal integration for development and testing but not have any access to accounts during production?

I've read the PayPal documentation and similar stackoverflow posts but can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the sample app by downloading it from [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp/PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App). It includes both the things sandbox enviornment & real account. You can take reference from this sample app.